# Nodejs/javascript - Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error shows up

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, promise

I'm getting:

> (node:38891) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)

Not sure why this is happening when the `setHeader` function is being called within the conditinal statement.

```js
cons y = proxy({
        target: BackendEndPoint,
        onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
            logger.info('initial frontend request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers))
            proxyReq.setHeader('CLIENT-ID', 'project')
            secretManager.awsSecretManger('frontend.encryptor').then(secret => {

                if (req.hostname == 'localhost') {
                    logger.info("setting claims AJ")
                    proxyReq.setHeader('X-CLAIMS', enc.encrypt(secret.key, JSON.stringify({
                        aid: "TestAid",
                        sessionId: "TestUUID",
                        roles: ["a1", "a2", "a3",
                            "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7"],
                        userName: "TestUSer"
                    })))
                    return
                } else if (req.claims) {
                    logger.info("setting claims found")
                    var proxyHeader = enc.encrypt(secret.key, req.claims)
                    return proxyReq.setHeader('X-CLAIMS', proxyHeader)
                }
            })
        },
        changeOrigin: (Origin === 'true')
    }
)
```

Calling the function:

```js
app.use('/api', authHeader, y)
```

Comment: What is the context for this function?  How is it called?

Comment: this is how i called it `app.use('/api', authHeader, y)`

Comment: I don't see anything here that suggests that you're sending a body before a header. So this at least suggests that .. perhaps `y` is fine, but there's something else that sends the body before headers can be sent.

Comment: does it make a difference that  `secretManager.awsSecretManger` is an async function?